# Get Puppeteer Page/Frame Handle for new page after `ElementHandle.click()`

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

Using `puppeteer`, I have a specific page that I am web-scraping for data and screenshot-ing for proof that the data is correct. The web page itself includes a button for creating a printer friendly version of the page. The button itself is implemented as an input of type `button` with no `target` attribute. Still, once clicked, the button opens the printer friendly version on a new page(tab) at `about:blank` that automatically opens up chrome's print dialog.

Whenever a new page opens up, I've typically done `browser.waitForTarget()` to try to capture the new target and work from there. The issue is that with any variation of code, I'm never able to find a `Page` that matches the page that was opened up. The closest I get is finding a `Target` of type `other` and a url of `chrome://print`.

Is there any way to find this type of target easily and even more get it's page (since `target.page()` only returns a page if the `target.type() === 'page'`? As a bonus, I'd like a way to potentially dismiss or ignore the window's print dialog, possibly even cancel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following to capture a new browser window:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false,
});

const page = await browser.newPage();
let page1;

browser.on("targetcreated", async (target) => {
  if (target.type() === "page") {
    page1 = await target.page();
  }
});
```

Or you can find the desired page using `browser.pages()` method. See the [documentation](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.7.0&show=api-browserpages) for more information.